# About the relation between the infinite matrices and $\ell^p-$spaces

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let
For $1\leq p<\infty$ suppose that $[t_{ij}]$ is an infinite $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ matrix such that $\Big(\sum_{j\in \Bbb N}t_{ij}x(j)\Big)_{i\in \Bbb N} \in \ell^p(\Bbb N),$ for all $x\in\ell^p(\Bbb N).$
If $B=[b_{ij}]$ is an infinite $ \Bbb N  \times\Bbb N,$ $0,1-$matrix, i.e., $b_{ij}\in \{0,1\},$ then can we show that $\Big(\sum_{j\in \Bbb N}b_{ij}t_{ij}x(j)\Big)_{i\in \Bbb N} \in \ell^p(\Bbb N),$ for all $x\in\ell^p(\Bbb N)?$
For example, when we assume that $t_{ij}\geq 0,$ then the claim is true. (because $f\in\ell^p(\Bbb N) $ is equivalent to $|f|\in\ell^p(\Bbb N) $)

Comment: wouldn't it be just that? $\Big(\sum_{j\in \Bbb N}b_{ij}t_{ij}x(j)\Big)\leq     \Big(\sum_{j\in \Bbb N}t_{ij}x(j)\Big)$